# Separate multi-line text from an element

Tags: jquery, html, node.js, dom, cheerio

I have an element that looks like this in the Developer Console:

```
<span>
  "Total Items: "
  "10"
</span>
```

I want to get only the second string (the "10") out of it, but `textContent`, `innerText`, `outerText`, `innerHTML` and `outerHTML` all concatenate the value into a single string (with no newline).

How can I detect where the split was in the original HTML?

I'm using Javascript (Node.js), so a JQuery or Cheerio solution would work for me.

Comment: We'd have to see the original `view-source:` HTML rather than dev tools, which renders elements in unusual ways. It's not clear that these nodes are two separate children, but if they are, you can collect them with code in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73692854/6243352), for example.

Answer (score 0):

Well it depends what breaks are you using, but try selecting the inner html and spliting it on the break itself

```
var splitString = $("span")[0].innerHTML.split("\n")
var secondLine = splitString[1]
```

Comment: This doesn't work because innerHTML doesn't contain a '\n'. I don't know what's causing the Developer Console to display it as it does...

Comment: @MikeMiller it doesnt have to have /n, it can have an arrow or something, can you post a screen or paste exactly what is in innerHTML

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have any newline you could use a RegEx for splitting:

`myString.split(/"(.*?)"/g)`

And then get the second value.

Comment: The html doesn't have quotes. It's just the string "Total items: 10" with no newlines or anything in between. I don't know what is causing the Developer Console to show it as it does.

Comment: The split by `:` and `trim()`. `"Total items: 10".split(':')[1].trim()`

Comment: But the text isn't always like that. They're essentially two random strings, always separated by a newline in the developer console, but apparently not in the original html. I haven't seen the original html; it's generated by JavaScript so it's not in the "view source". I've only seen it in the developer console, which seems to be the only place this mystery newline shows up.

Comment: You need to find an anchor point or something that it stays the same every time the text is generated otherwise I don't see how you could predict where to split. For example if you know that you want to capture every time just the digits (Ex. 10) just use a regEx to match that constant behaviour