# How to get a text that's separated by different HTML tags in Cheerio

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, web-scraping, cheerio

I'm trying to get the specific text strings below as separated outputs e.g. (scrape them from the HTML below):

```js
let text = "Thats the first text I need";
let text2 = "The second text I need";
let text3 = "The third text I need";
```

I really don't know how to get a text that's separated by different HTML tags.

```html
<p>
   <span class="hidden-text"><span class="ft-semi">Count:</span>31<br></span>
   <span class="ft-semi">Something:</span> That's the first text I need
   <span class="hidden-text"><span class="ft-semi">Something2:</span> </span>The second text I need
   <br><span class="ft-semi">Something3:</span> The third text I need
</p>
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926580/find-text-string-using-jquery

Comment: Rather than all those line breaks, maybe just use block-level elements like divs.

Comment: What have you tried? jQuery makes this kind of thing pretty easy.

Comment: I just want to scrape the text from this website and it has a structure like that

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can iterate the child nodes of the `<p>` and grab any `nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE`s that have nonempty content:

```js
for (const e of document.querySelector("p").childNodes) {
  if (e.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && e.textContent.trim()) {
    console.log(e.textContent.trim());
  }
}

// or to make an array:
const result = [...document.querySelector("p").childNodes]
  .filter(e =>
    e.nodeType === Node.TEXT_NODE && e.textContent.trim()
  )
  .map(e => e.textContent.trim());
console.log(result);
```

```html
<p>
  <span class="hidden-text">
    <span class="ft-semi">Count:</span>
    31
    <br>
  </span>
  <span class="ft-semi">Something:</span>
  That's the first text I need
  <span class="hidden-text">
    <span class="ft-semi">Something2:</span>
  </span>
  The second text I need
  <br>
  <span class="ft-semi">Something3:</span>
  The third text I need
</p>
```

In Cheerio:

```js
const cheerio = require("cheerio"); // 1.0.0-rc.12

const html = `
<p>
  <span class="hidden-text">
    <span class="ft-semi">Count:</span>
    31
    <br>
  </span>
  <span class="ft-semi">Something:</span>
  That's the first text I need
  <span class="hidden-text">
    <span class="ft-semi">Something2:</span>
  </span>
  The second text I need
  <br>
  <span class="ft-semi">Something3:</span>
  The third text I need
</p>
`;

const $ = cheerio.load(html);
const result = [...$("p").contents()]
  .filter(e => e.type === "text" && $(e).text().trim())
  .map(e => $(e).text().trim());

console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this and see if it works:

```
html = `your sample html above`

domdoc = new DOMParser().parseFromString(html, "text/html")
result = domdoc.evaluate('//text()[not(ancestor::span)]', domdoc, null, XPathResult.ORDERED_NODE_SNAPSHOT_TYPE, null);

for (let i = 0; i < result.snapshotLength; i++) {
  target = result.snapshotItem(i).textContent.trim()
  if (target.length > 0) {
    console.log(target);
  }
}
```

Using your sample html, the output should be:

```
"That's the first text I need"
"The second text I need"
"The third text I need"
```

Comment: Is there a nodejs alternative?